# Excel/VBA - Chart range based on nonempties of column

Tags: excel, vba

Consider a list of dates showing in column A, with associated values in `column B`. Some of the values in `column B` are shown, some are not (i.e. "" resulting from an IF statement).

What are my possibilities to create a chart which automatically adjusts it range to *only* contain the dates in `A` and values in `B`, based on the non-hidden values in `column B` (ie which are NOT ""). It should be able to recognize if any changes happen to values in `column B` and ajust accordingly.

For instance (no headers), `B1` is "", `B2:B3` has values, `B4` is "", the chart should only be based on row 2 and 3.

Comment: Let's see the code you have tried already.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel you can use a return value of NA() rather than "" to ensure a point isn't plotted. You would need to consider if also implementing something similar for the axis (so hide associated Date). Below is first google search that came back for me.

See here: [hiding data points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53719/hiding-data-points-in-excel-line-charts)

Comment: Yeah, but depending on chart type, there still may be an empty category where the "" or #N/A would be plotted.